# Extend "Save and Close" event

Tags: acumatica

I need to do certain operation once user clicks on "Save & Close" and "Save" button. Please suggest. Once user clicks on any of these button, I need to do some custom operation.

-Krunal

Comment: did you try overriding the persist event of the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RowPersisting or RowPersisted event.